# C#: Print POCO class's full qualified name without affect concatenation of any two string properties with the use of ToString() method

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have scenario to print the Student (First name and Last name) name of the `Student` class when I call the `ToString()` method of that class object like below.

```
Console.WriteLine(new Student() { FirstName = "Sachin", LastName = "Tendulkar" }.ToString());
```

So, I have `overrride` the `ToString()` method in `Student's POCO class` as below

```
namespace TestSOF_Console
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string StudentCode { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
        }
    }
}
```

Later, I have an additional query to get full qualified name of the `Student` class as `TestSOF_Console.Student` without affect Student full name with use of `ToString()` method.

```
Console.WriteLine(new Student() { FirstName = "Sachin", LastName = "Tendulkar" }.ToString());
```

The above code will allow me to choose what I need to print (whether class name or student name)...

Is there any possibility to achieve this both with `ToString()` method?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'fully qualified name', as you don't show any example that's different than the ToString() method's output.  One option you do have is to overload the ToString() method to supply different information and/or formatting.

Comment: @tinstaafl I have override the `ToString()` method already to print Student full name. Now, I want to print the fully qualified name of the class (as per my  example: `TestSOF_Console.Student`) when I call ToString() method. Since, it already print Student full name. My question is: Is there any possibility to print both with `ToString()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add whatever literal string you want inside the quotes before the first brace, `("TestSOF_Console.Student - {0} {1}", FirstName, LastName)`

If you need to make it optional simply overload the ToString() method:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
}

public string ToString(string header)
{
    return string.Format(header + " - {0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
}
```

To call the overload simply add a string as a parameter to the ToString() method-

`new Student() { FirstName = "Sachin", LastName = "Tendulkar" }.ToString("TestSOF_Console.Student")`

Comment: I have got student full name in so many places in my whole project. If I do the same as your answer, I will need to implement the logic to split in all those places (This is angainst of Open-Close principle). What if I need is: I would like to print the class name without affect my previous implementation

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu - I added more for you

Comment: One small correction. I need to print only base class name. So, I simple modified your overloaded method to 
`public string ToString(bool PrintBaseClassName)
 {
      return base.ToString();
 }` Anyhow, thanks!

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu - That should be fine.  Glad you found this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Before the `.ToString()` method was overridden the value produced would have been `TestSOF_Console.Student`, so I assume when you ask for the full qualified name that that is what you mean.

To get that value, simply output `typeof(TestSOF_Console.Student).FullName`.

So, to do what you want you just need to write this:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(TestSOF_Console.Student).FullName + " " + new Student() { FirstName = "Sachin", LastName = "Tendulkar" }.ToString());
```

Answer (score -2):

No, you can call the [GetType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx) method intstead.